# show pandastable with initial focus on specific row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
from pandastable import Table, TableModel

class TestApp(Frame):
        """Basic test frame for the table"""
        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            self.parent = parent
            Frame.__init__(self)
            self.main = self.master
            self.main.geometry('600x400+200+100')
            self.main.title('Table app')
            f = Frame(self.main)
            f.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)
            df = TableModel.getSampleData()
            self.table = pt = Table(f, dataframe=df,
                                    showtoolbar=True, showstatusbar=True)
            pt.show()
            pt.movetoSelection(row = 23, col=1)
            return

app = TestApp()
app.mainloop()
```

I want to show a `pd.df` using the `pandastable` `library` and I need the initially focused row to be one down the bottom of the `df` and the table to have scrolled down at that line upon its drawing.

I have found the (most probably) relevant method which should be  `movetoSelection(row=None, col=0, idx=None, offset=0)` with the description in the `library`'s [documentation](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/pandastable/latest/pandastable.pdf) being rather limited to "Move to a specific row/col, updating table", which nonetheless should do the job.

I am calling the `method` with `pt.movetoSelection(row = 23, col=1)` because I found a similar use in the `library`'s [github page](https://github.com/dmnfarrell/pandastable/blob/master/pandastable/dialogs.py)(script line 1272): `table.movetoSelection(row=i,col=j,offset=3)`. Unfortunately, this produces the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\svobodov\Desktop\data\tests\print_df_in_window\2. pandastable\0.2 return marked lines\test.py", line 21, in <module>
    app = TestApp()
  File "C:\Users\svobodov\Desktop\data\tests\print_df_in_window\2. pandastable\0.2 return marked lines\test.py", line 18, in __init__
    pt.movetoSelection(row = 23, col=1)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandastable\core.py", line 2397, in movetoSelection
    self.drawSelectedRow()
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandastable\core.py", line 3297, in drawSelectedRow
    x1,y1,x2,y2 = self.getCellCoords(row,0)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandastable\core.py", line 2067, in getCellCoords
    x1=self.col_positions[col]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I have had a look at the source scripts and the method's definition in `core.py` and by doing some printings I found that `self.col_positions` is an empty `list` but I can hardly understand why that is the case.

To describe the current behaviour aside of the error message, when running the script the given row does get highlighted/selected but the focus does not go down to that line, i.e. the top rather than the bottom lines of the table appear.

The example is taken from the `library`'s [docs](https://pandastable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html), only the line with `pt.movetoSelection(row = 23, col=1)` has been added.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to move the selection to a non-existent row. What's magic about row `23` anyway?

Comment: @martineau If you run the code you'll see that the table has 400 rows so the row does exist. And there is nothing magical about it, any row that goes further down below the top 15 would be good enough to showcase the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming from the author of the library after opening an issue on `github`, this appears to be a minor bug, but a workaround is to `redraw` the `table` just before calling `movetoSelection`, so:

```
pt.show()
pt.redraw()
pt.movetoSelection(row = yourDesiredRowIdx, col=yourDesiredColIdx)
```